# Set Addition proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

Prove that for any two sets we have the following: A∪B=A+B−A∩B
Not sure what the + means here. Do i just add the two sets together including the duplicated elements?

Yes sorry it should be ∣A∪B∣=∣A∣+∣B∣−∣A∩B∣.Thanks Bernard for the correction

Comment: In most of the texts I read $A+B = \{a + b: a \in A, b \in B\}$ and $A - B = A \setminus B$. But with this definition your set equality is wrong. Consider $A = \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $B = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$. Would it be something like $m(A \cup B) = m(A) + m(B) - m(A \cap B)$ instead, where $m$ may possibly be probability or the cardinality?

Comment: You should add more context.  Where did you see this?

Comment: It was on one of my lecture slides, but there was no proof to it.

Answer (score 1):

I tyhink the correct formula is about the number of elements of the sets:
$$\lvert A\cup B\rvert=\lvert A\rvert+\lvert B\rvert-\lvert A\cap B\rvert.$$